# How to check SQL Compact Auto Shrink setting?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-ce, corruption

Quick context of my problem, some of our compact databases in production are going corrupt and we need to do investigate the cause. I found some great pointers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343194/resolving-corruption-in-sql-server-compact-edition-database-files), one of them being "Turn off Auto-Shrink".

So my question is How do I **check** what my Auto Shrink level is on an existing compact database?

With Sql Server I can use sys.databases as follows:

```
SELECT
   name,
   is_auto_shrink_on
FROM sys.databases
```

But alas sys.database does not exist in SQL Compact (understandably so).

I've read here at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.100).aspx) that you can **set** the Auto_Shrink value in the connection string and they mention that the default Auto_Shrink value is 60. This is great, but in my case I need to find out what the Auto_Shrink is on an existing database, not change it.

Does Auto_Shrink perhaps work differently with a compact database and I am misunderstanding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is specified as a per session setting, so you need to look at the connection string in use.

It is also important the client uses the latest SQL Compact enigine binaries.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Erik, that's the answer I was looking for. I also do have the latest Compact binaries.